# Error : Undefined index - PHP, MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting profile image in folder and in database table, image is well uploaded to the "uploads" folder, but not inserting in mysql database table. I am getting this error:

`Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in C:\wamp\www\project\upload_image.php on line 10`

From the following code:

`upload_image.php`

```
<?php
include_once('dbconn.php');
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
  $fileToUpload = $_POST['fileToUpload'];
  $sql="INSERT INTO profile_image (user_id,fileToUpload) VALUES ('$user_id', '$fileToUpload')";
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } 
  else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}

// Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
      echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
      $uploadOk = 0;
    }

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
  // if everything is ok, try to upload file
} 
else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file))     {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
  } 
  else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
?>
```

`HTML code`

```
<form method="post" action="upload_image.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <?php if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){?>
  <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo ($_SESSION['id']);}else{header("Location: login.php");}?>">
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Show your profile_image table structure

Comment: Where is line no 10 in your code?

Comment: use $_FILES instead of $fileToUpload = $_POST['fileToUpload'];

Comment: `$fileToUpload = $_POST['fileToUpload'];` you trying to get the file upload as `$_POST` try `$_FILES`

Comment: @Raja Now getting this error `Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\project\upload_image.php on line 11` This is my line number 11 `$sql="INSERT INTO profile_image (user_id,fileToUpload) VALUES ('$user_id', '$fileToUpload')";`

Comment: do you want to save upload file name

Comment: [This page discusses the reason for the notice](http://siliconstation.com/how-fix-php-notice-undefined-index/), even though your actual problem is elsewhere. Oh, and study about SQL injection before putting your code anywhere near a live site!

Comment: @Raja Error removed but image name is not inserting in database.

Comment: @novice try to print the `$_FILES['fileToUpload']` so you'll come to know the array structure ,then save filename accordingly.

Comment: @Raja `echo "<pre/>";print_r($fileToUpload);die;` i got this `AIS14E.JPG`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fileToUpload = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
```

Try this.

Comment: Error removed but image name is not inserting in database.

Comment: `Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\project\upload_image.php on line 11` This is my line number 11 `$sql="INSERT INTO profile_image (user_id,fileToUpload) VALUES ('$user_id', '$fileToUpload')";`

Comment: On line number 10 use this. $fileToUpload = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];

Comment: I just echo the sql query check this out `INSERT INTO profile_image (user_id, fileToUpload) VALUES ('1', 'AIS14E.JPG')` but not inserting in database.

Comment: because you are not executing this query.

Comment: How to execute this ?

Comment: if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
 mysql_query($sql) or die('There is some error.');
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} replace this condition and add this.

Comment: Show me your table structure of profile_image table.

Comment: `INSERT INTO profile_image (user_id, fileToUpload) VALUES ('1', 'AIS35H.JPG')File is an image - image/jpeg.There is some error.`

Comment: `Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra
---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------
 id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment
 user_id | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |
 image   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |`

Comment: $sql = INSERT INTO profile_image (user_id,image) VALUES ('$user_id', '$fileToUpload')"; Change this.

Comment: mysql_query($sql) or die('There is some error.');

Replace this line with these lines.
$res = mysql_query($sql);
if ($res) {
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
  echo 'There was a database error: '.mysql_error();
}

Answer (score 1):

The **fileToUpload** variable does not exist as a $_POST

```
 $_POST['fileToUpload'];
```

If has to be set as $_FILE as was previously used

```
 $_FILE['fileToUpload'];
```

However $_FILE[''] array is broken up into different components and you need to select the part of the array you are after.

For example if you were trying to save the name of the file to the database use

```
$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is an another way to solve your problem:

```php
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$uploadOk = 1;

if(isset($_POST["submit"])||!empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])) {
    $target_file =$target_dir.basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        $check["mime"];
        $uploadOk = 1;
        if (file_exists($target_file)) {
            echo "File already exists.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Check file size
        if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
            echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

            } else {
       if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg") {
            echo "Only JPG, JPEG & PNG files are allowed.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
}}
?>
```